# Reflection. Executing non-static method with parameters

Tags: java, android, reflection

I need to execute some method via reflection

method to execute

```
public void someMethod(int value1, int value2, String str, int value3)
{
    try
    {
        // some code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is execution code

```
public static void execute()
{
    try
    {
        String          className = "some.class";
        String          classPath = "some.pack.name" + ":" + "some.class";
        PathClassLoader loader    = new dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(classPath, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

        Class           clazz     = Class.forName(className, true, loader);
        Method          method    = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", Integer.class, Integer.class, String.class, Integer.class); 
        Object          object    = clazz.newInstance();

        method.invoke(object, 1, 2, "str", 3);
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

But I gets error

```
01-22 21:44:52.286: W/System.err(10877): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: someMethod [class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer]
01-22 21:44:52.286: W/System.err(10877):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
01-22 21:44:52.286: W/System.err(10877):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:640)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method declaration `someMethod` uses primitive `int` parameters, so change the line which gets the method to the following to use the `int` class instead of `Integer` class:

```
clazz.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", int.class, int.class, String.class, int.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

The class literal `Integer.class` represents the `Integer` class, not the `int` primitive datatype.  When finding methods, reflection won't performing the unboxing conversion to convert from `Integer` to `int`.

Use [`Integer.TYPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE) to represent the `int` primitive type.

> The `Class` instance representing the primitive type `int`.

```
Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class, Integer.TYPE);
```

You can also use the class literal `int.class`, as [Section 15.8.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) states:

> A *class literal* is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or **primitive type**, or the pseudo-type `void`, followed by a '.' and the token `class`.

(bold emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you too! Both answers works. But I got another exception java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class someClass; no empty constructor

Comment: The `newInstance` method on `Class` attempts to invoke the no-argument constructor, which apparently you don't have in your class.  You'll need to find the proper constructor with `Class`'s `getConstructor` method (similar to `getMethod`), then you can invoke `newInstance` on the resulting `Constructor` object, passing in the appropriate arguments.